# How to combine value in datagridview table with custom

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

[this my datagridview2, from contact.db that have 2 columns : no_tlp (telephone number), and Contact name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQAVH.png)

[and this is my datagridview1, from sms.db that have 3 columns : id_thread, address (phone no),body(sms text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQSsF.png)

i want to combine both datagridview so they can show; id_thread, contact name, and body sms, then throw to datagridview3

but i have problem that phone number in datagridview1 & datagridview2 have different value like +62 and 0 (country code),

i have plan to change all 0 on phone number to +62, and combine both where phone_no in contact = phone_no in sms

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for change the php number you  can

```
update contact
set no_tlp = concat('+62', right(no_tlp, length(no_tlp) -1))
where no_tlp like '0%';
```

once you ha update the n_tlp you can select from both the table

```
 select contact.*, sms.*
 from contact 
 inner join sms on contact.n_tlp = sms.address
```

Comment: Query: update tb_src_contact set no_tlp = concat('+62', right(no_tlp, lenght(no_tlp) -1)) where no_tlp like '0%'

Error Code: 1305
FUNCTION db_smsfor.lenght does not exist

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.064 sec

Comment: i have update the answer because there is a typo lenght instead of length .. try with the right query ... and be sure you are using mysql